# Is there a limit for how "good" a numerical method can be?

Tags: soft-question, numerical-methods, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra

Multiplying two matrices $A \cdot B$ of size $n \times n$ in the trivial way requires $n^3$ computations. However, more efficient algorithms such as the [Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) have a lower complexity of approximately $\mathcal{O}(n^{2.8})$. There's even the [Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) of theoretical complexity $\mathcal{O}(n^{2.37})$.

It seems unlikely that there would be for example a linear function that computes the matrix product, but is there a theoretical limit as to how effective any algorithm to multiply matrices must be, would for example $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ be possible?

I'm also interested in extending the question beyound matrix multiplication. Are there such "theoretical lower bounds on complexity" for accomplishing a certain task with numerical methods (like multiplying two matrices) in general?

Comment: The obvious lower bound is how many things must be read off in order to make the computation. The matrix product is a function of the $2n^2$ entries, and no entry can safely be omitted from the computation in general, so $\mathcal O(n^2)$ is a lower bound for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Or perhaps to be more formal, matrix multiplication has a complexity of $\Omega(n^{2})$. :-)

Comment: @Dustan Ok, that's a good point. But can we say anything about whether it's possible to create an algorithm that actually has that complexity?

Comment: In general that's a very difficult problem.

Comment: In fact, I think even an optimal algorithm for vanilla multiplication of integers is unknown. (I wrote floating point numbers initially, but that's not what the lecture I remember seeing claimed.)

Comment: The [Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) (or at least a refinement from 2011) has complexity $O(n^{2.3727})$, so that's quite a bit closer to the optimum than $O(n^3)$. It is, according to wiki, the fastest known to date, but it has such a large overhead that it's not practical in use. Also note that, according to that wiki article, it is not yet actually known that matrix multiplication can be done in $O(n^2)$, although it is likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [survey paper](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/sigactcolumn.pdf) by Virginia Vassilevska Williams who showed the currently best bound of $\omega \leq 2.373$.

In the introduction she says:

> The best known lower bounds for the problem are of the form $c \cdot n^2$ for explicit constants $c \leq 3$. Perhaps because of this, a majority of experts believe that there should exist an essentially quadratic time algorithm for matrix multiplication. Some prominent experts, however,
>   such as Strassen, have also expressed the opinion that matrix multiplication requires strictly more
>   than quadratic time. The answer has evaded computer science researchers for more than 40 years!

Thus it seems that we don't know more than $2 \leq \omega \leq 2.373$.